# JSR250: CommonAnnotations for Java, 2.3: @Resource methods must be setters that follow the standard JavaBeans convention

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere

**I am getting a problem on this line:**

```
@Resource 
public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

**The message is:**

JSR250: CommonAnnotations for Java, 2.3: 
**@Resource** methods must be setters that follow the standard JavaBeans convention. 
i.e. void "setProperty( value)" for " property".

ProjGatewayBean.java    /DocViewerEJB/src/main/java/com/tscdv/document/b/beans  line 72 Annotation Problem

**What could be the problem, and how do I resolve it?**

I have upgraded editor from Rad 7.5 to 8 and maven 2 to 3. This happens just after importing the maven projects, but I have no errors on any pom files.

I have **some other issue** with two xml files that might be related, separated into a new post:

[Error: Projects containing version <unknown> deployment descriptors require XMI-format bindings or extensions files. ibm-web-bnd.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243424/error-projects-containing-version-unknown-deployment-descriptors-require-xmi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the context attribute messageDrivenContext in your class and change your method as follow:

```
@Resource 
public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext context) {
   this.messageDrivenContext = context;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Great! This must have been an error in the pre rad 8 version as well.